# Can SVG have malicious content?

Tags: security, svg, websecurity

I don't know very details about SVG standard and it's extensions. But, I've have read, that SVG images can execute some scripts.

Is it safe to display any (user uploaded) SVG image on site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be safe as long as you load them as an `<img>`. That includes equivalent uses such as with `background-image`.  But **not safe** when inlined, or loaded via `<object>` etc.

The browser follows special rules when SVG images are loaded this way.  For example, the SVG must be self-contained (ie. no external resources), scripts will not be executed, and `:visited` style rules will not be applied.

See: https://www.w3.org/wiki/SVG_Security

Comment: What if SVG is loaded using base64 encoded data inside `src` of the `img` tag? For example: `<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,notRealData..." />`. Is it still safe?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the source of the SVG data is. The same rules apply.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, SVG can contain malicious content. And, it depends on browser, whether it respects SVG Security. Therefore, rather don't count on that.

Comment: SVG has the `<script>` element. Anything that runs a script can, in theory, do malicious things.  "depends on browser" is an odd way of putting it. Browsers have a mode where some features of SVG are not available.